# fs.createReadStream loop not completing

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, electron

I am iterating through an object containing local files, all of which definitely exist, reading them into a buffer and incrementing a counter when each completes. The problem is despite there being 319 files to read, printing out the counter to the console rarely, if ever, shows it getting through all of them. It mysteriously stops in the 200's somewhere... different every time and without throwing any errors.

I have this running in an electron project and the built app works seamlessly on a Mac but won't get through this loop on windows! I've recently updated all the packages and have been through in other areas and made the necessary adjustments and the whole app is working perfectly.. except this and it's driving me mad!

Here's the code:

```
$.each(compare_object, function(key, item) {
    console.log(item.local_path); // this correctly prints out every single file path
    var f = fs.createReadStream(item.local_path);

    f.on('data', function(buf) {
        // normally some other code goes in here but I've simplified it right down for the purposes of getting it working!
    });

    f.on('end', function(err) {
        num++;
        console.log(num); // this rarely reached past 280 out of 319 files. Always different though.
    });

    f.on('error', function(error) {
        console.log(error); // this never fires.
        num++;
    });
});
```

I'm wondering if there's a cache that's maxing out or if I should be destroying the buffer after 'end' every time but nothing I've read suggest this and even when I tried it made no difference. A lot of the example expect you to be piping it somewhere, which I'm not. In the full code it creates a hash of the complete file and adds it to the object for each of the local files.

Comment: What are you doing with data? can you explain it in a few words, are you aggregating data somehow?

Comment: In general: you are mixing synchronous code with asynchronous. Your code will open 200(or how many?) files simultaneously which can be an issue.

Comment: @kharandziuk I'm creating a hash of each local file that is read and then saving that hash to a previously created object. The end goal is to be able to compare the local file hash to that same file's hash in dropbox to see if the file has been amended. It's been working perfectly until I updated electron and all the node modules - why would it have changed?

Comment: There were at least 3 versions of the stream API in node. Possibly, you updated a version of electron which updated a version of node which provided  you a new version of stream API.

https://medium.com/the-node-js-collection/a-brief-history-of-node-streams-pt-2-bcb6b1fd7468 - here you can find a brief history of streams

Comment: `f.on('data', function(buf) {` - do you construct the whole file here by appending the buffers?

Comment: Yes. At the beginning of the loop I create a new object for that file: `var hasher = dch.create();` and then in the `f.on('data', function(buf) {` section I append `buf` to it with this: `hasher.update(buf);`. Then on `end` I create the hash and add it to a global object. I'm using this ([dropbox-api-content-hasher](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-api-content-hasher/blob/master/js-node/dropbox-content-hasher.js)) to create the hash

Comment: https://gist.github.com/kharandziuk/e37787502611938086893af198a824ed - can I ask you to try the code from this gist? Feel free to ask questions

Comment: Thank you! Trying this now.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the loop is completing here. The problem: you are putting some handlers which are async. The easiest possible solution here is to rewrite your code without streams.

```js
const fs = require('fs')
const util = require('util')


const asyncReadFile = util.promisify(fs.readFile)

//.. this loop goes into some function with async or you can use readFileAsync
for (let [key, item] of Object.entries(compare_object)) {
  const data = await asyncReadFile(item.local_path)
  ///. here goes data handling
}
```